# Followup to Stock Market Probability Question

Tags: probability, word-problem

I asked this question a while back ([Why is trading in the stock market 50% probability instead of 25% probability?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2577034/why-is-trading-in-the-stock-market-50-probability-instead-of-25-probability)) and the answer that was given to me is:

(1/2 * 1/2) + (1/2 * 1/2) = 1/4 + 1/4 = 2/4 = 1/2 = 50% chance

I've thought about it some more and I realised that I don't really understand the calculation as I thought I did.

My thought process:

(1/2 * 1/2) -> why multiplication? There are two independent events (buy or short-sell and win or loss). The first "coin toss" = 50% and then a second toss results also in 50%. Wouldn't that be 1/2 + 1/2 = 1 (which is incorrect)? I thought that multiplication means 1 single event (that is, two "coin tosses" at the same time)?

And then the addition part... if it's adding, then that means I'm adding two independent events, right? So that really means the first "coin toss" is (1/2 * 1/2) and the second toss is (1/2 * 1/2). Did I at least understand the addition part?

I was hoping someone could walk me through the calculation... sort of /explainlikeimfive. I really would like to understand it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication means "you need the situation *both* to be true".

For example, if I do not want to get wet in rains, there are two cases

> It does not rain
>   It does rain but I have my umbrella

Assume all things have probability assigned (and those probabilities are independent).  Then I will say the whole probability of me not getting wet is

> P(no rain) + P(has rain) $\times$ P(have umbrella)

The addition means "two separate cases", and multiplication means "I need both to be true in order to be safe".

So yup, for the stock market, "1/2 $\times$ 1/2" definitely means that you need **both** cases to happen in order to earn money, so on and so forth.

Comment: @starchy Yes this is what I meant.  Addition and multiplication are corresponding to "or" and "and" correctly in your statements.

Comment: @starchy it certainly takes time.  Try to apply probability thoughts to everyday life and think carefully "what I meant by 'and' here?" (like the previous 'and' I have used).  I'm still getting the hang of some logic problems, sometimes they are quite annoying XD

Comment: I will point out that the "and" calculation happens to be $P(A\text{and}B)$, more correctly written as $P(A\cap B)$ expands as $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ if and *only* if $A$ and $B$ are *independent* events.  (*do not confuse the terms independent and mutually exclusive*).  More generally, one would have $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B\mid A)$.

Comment: Agree, sorry for the fact that I didn't clarify at the moment (even I tried to say it in the answer).  So to be very honest the probability is not exactly 0.5 since you are not randomly selling or buying, and there are many other factors affecting our decision.  But generally speaking, if we say the buying and selling is independent, the multiplication is correct.  We can also consider the stock market as a zero-sum game (kind of).  Then we know that there are millionaires making money out of stock, which implies that we will have negative expected value of money gain (ofc this is sloppy)

Comment: A final comment, negative expected value of money gain does not imply (not in the other way around too) that P(lose)>0.5.  Consider you earn $\$$1 every time and lose $\$$100000000 with probability 0.01.  You will get a negative expected value but P(lose)=0.01.